# `RuntimeError: unreachable` while using polkadot js to do sr25519 sign

Tags: polkadot-js, wasm

```js
await cryptoWaitReady();

const json = JSON.parse(xxx);
const keyring = new Keyring({ ss58Format: 42 });
const pair = keyring.addFromPair(decoded, json.meta, 'sr25519');
// const pair = keyring.addFromUri('//Alice', null, 'sr25519');
const sig = pair.sign(..);
```

Everything works well if I use `//Alice` to sign. But if I use json key to sign then I got this error.

If I remove the `await cryptoWaitReady();` I'll get `The WASM interface has not been initialized.`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the `xxx` is an ed25519 style key.

I shouldn't set it to `sr25519`.

And the runtime doesn't provide an interface to sign this; check https://github.com/polkadot-js/common/issues/929#issuecomment-813324953.